# Firebase - Get url on login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Can somebody please refer me to an example of Firebase login and redirection ,
lets say i want a certain user to get specific data on login?
would be great if it would be in angularfire, but any example will do for now
thanks!

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on numerous factors.

For example, are you using email and password based authentication?:

```
$scope.login = function(username, password) {
var fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(fb);
fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
    email: username,
    password: password
}).then(function(authData) {
    // Get information here
    // Redirect here
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("ERROR: " + error);
});
}
```

In the above scenario, you'd log in with an email and password, and right before you redirect in your promise, you would grab whatever information you need from Firebase.

For Oauth logins and even email and password logins, my preference is to get user specific information after the redirect.  The assumption is that the redirect location is protected and the user wouldn't be able to see it unless authenticated.

Or of course you could authenticate via a popup too.

There are a lot of different things you can do.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithpassword.html

Regards,